How can I bypass FastAPI to directly upload files to a European Gluster volume from Europe?
I have a WordPress server located in the US that mounts two directories to separate GlusterFS volumes. One volume is hosted on US servers, and the other on servers in Europe.
Additionally, I run FastAPI endpoints on the WordPress server to handle file uploads and the extraction of ZIP files to these Gluster volumes. However, when uploading ZIP files from Europe, I notice that uploads to the US Gluster volume are about twice as fast as uploads to the European Gluster volume.
I suspect this is because the FastAPI endpoint, hosted in the US, is acting as an intermediary. This means the file is first sent from Europe to the FastAPI endpoint in the US, then redirected back to the European Gluster volume.
I've considered setting up a separate FastAPI server in Europe to handle uploads directly to the European Gluster volume, potentially reducing the latency and improving upload speed for European users.
Is there a way to configure my setup so that I can directly upload files to the European Gluster volume from Europe, bypassing the US-based FastAPI server as a middleman?
Additional Context:

The WordPress server is located in the US.
Both Gluster volumes are mounted on this server, one pointing to US storage and the other to European storage.
I want to keep the current infrastructure as much as possible and avoid major reconfiguration if possible.

Any suggestions or best practices to improve the upload speed and minimize latency would be greatly appreciated!
